# Django-cms and SQLite performance

Tags: django, sqlite, postgresql, django-cms

I have a corporate website with django-cms and with a SQLite database that has only a few updates per month. The majority are reads. It will be less than 5000k requests per day.

My deployment is in a Cpanel server with apache and wsgi. I need to know first if I should be worried about the usage of SQLite and if PostgreSQL in this situation will be faster and less resources consumption (because it is already installed and running on server).

This site use a 11MB SQLite file. Is this file in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite will be faster than PostgreSQL except in cases of high contention.  If you only update a few times per month, then SQLite will amost certainly be faster than PostgreSQL.

You may still choose to use PostgreSQL for other reasons (i.e. if you need network access to your data), but probably not for performance reasons.

Comment: Is there any possibility to appear `database locked` and random `no matching query` even if this exists?

Comment: @balsagoth: Even if what exists?

Comment: the page that i'm trying to view.

Comment: Well I have no way of knowing what page you're trying to view... or how that relates to locked databases.

Comment: What i'm trying to explain is that sometimes the same page that appear s normally gives me that error. I hit refresh and the page appears again.

Comment: @balsagoth: That sounds like a completely unrelated problem. I suggest asking a new question about those errors.